# How to do ajax pagination with QueryString Parameters in Django?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I want to create pagination with multiple QueryString Parameters, I created regular pagination with Django only but while creating Ajax pagination with multiple QueryString I faced  problems.

**I got this error:
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'**

My views:

```
def products(request):
    products = Products.objects.all()
    if   request.method == 'GET':
                per_page = request.GET.get("option")
                
                
                paginator = Paginator(products, per_page)  # data from get request is not passed properly
                page = request.GET.get('page')
                try:
                    product_list = paginator.page(page)
                except PageNotAnInteger:
                   
                     product_list = paginator.page(1)
                except EmptyPage:
               
                     product_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, './item/shop.html', {'products': products})
```

My Query parameter submitting html:

```
<select name="show-product-count" class="form-control" id= "show-product-count">
                                            <option value="9">Show 9</option>
                                            <option value="12" selected="selected">Show 12</option>
                                            <option value="24">Show 24</option>
                                            <option value="36">Show 36</option>
                                        </select>
```

My Ajax/Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#show-product-count").on("change", function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
  
    $.ajax({
      url : $(this).data('url'),
      type : "GET",
      data : {"option" : selectedValue},
      dataType : "json",
      success : function(){
  
      }
    });
  });



})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a get request with data in the body (not sure if it is even possible), yet your view is checking the query parameters.

Change your ajax request so it will send the data as query parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#show-product-count").on("change", function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
 
    $.ajax({
      url : $(this).data('url')+'?option='+selectedValue,
      type : "GET",
      success : function(){
  
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Still I am getting same error:

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

I want to pass just value to per_page variable via GET request.

Do you have any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: If `per_page` is None, it means it is not passed in the request. you can use a default value `per_page = request.GET.get("option", 1)`

Comment: I am getting this error on console:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/undefined?option=9


Response is : Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/undefined?option=9

I think I need to pass paginator url after /products/
How can I do that with Ajax?

Comment: `$(this).data('url')` is wrong.. set it up correctly